# how to protect a php page where there is no form too check against

Tags: php, security, error-handling, authorization, user-experience

im trying to finish my site and ensuring that the user cannot see anything that might help them in malicious ways or give them a bad experience on the site.

So for my pages where e.g login.php i check the request method, if its post continue if not then 404 etc.

However i have a couple of pages that gather some information from the database and i include them in the page. Some of them are quite large / complex so i prefer doing this to keep things tidier.

How can i go about redirecting the user to a 404 if they directly access these pages instead of them just being included?

Thanks. Hope you know what i mean! :)

Comment: Have them login, set a session variable noting that they are logged in and check for it on secure pages. That's it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use htpasswd authorization.

Comment: i usually put the files that are just for inclusion into a folder that is not accessable from the web.

Comment: i can see that being an easier way and i think i will do that as well. However i think i would like a double fall back just incase for some reason that my js fails and ajax call doesnt work so directs the user to the proccessing page etc.

Comment: Aside from floww's excellent suggestion, you can use `rewrite-rules` in `.htaccess` to ensure the server redirects all requests to only allowed scripts (typically one portal script).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that you can use some simple tricks.

where you want to include files, instead of simply

```
include('db.php')
```

do:

```
$including = 'yes';
include('db.php');
```

and in first lines of db.php:

```
if (!isset($including)) {
  //show 404
  exit;
}
//db job
```

so it does it's job if included, and shows a 404 if it is called directly.

**Alternatively:**

the first trick (and DEFINE) may be safer but if you don't want to change every file that includes the file;

just in db.php:

```
if (basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
  //show 404
  exit;
}
//db job
```

Comment: One observation on this approach, which has bitten me in practice: the variable `$including` can be set to null (or unset) prior to the include, causing the test in `db.php` to pass as though it wasn't being included.  The `define` approach in my answer does not allow this -- defines cannot be undefined or redefined.

Comment: `include` should be just after `$including=` , but yes!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php // top file, eg login.php
define('IN_SCRIPT', true);
include('infopage.php');
?>

<?php // included file, eg infopage.php
if (! defined('IN_SCRIPT')) {
   // log message, throw header, etc.
   // this is a direct access
   exit(0);
}

// do whatever
?>
```

Alternatively, consider moving your info pages out of the web visible space.